# Errors on urls Lots of extra information

Tags: url, seo

Can someone help?

Hi i am having issues with my urls when i use rank checker i get lots off script coming through when the website is indexed.

here is a screenshot i have hovered over one off the url to show all the information coming through with it.

[image]

I have no idea why this might be happening

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then don't use rankchecker, if it has problems. Noone here can support that stupid software, that we haven't heard of before. Not a programming question. Ask the vendor.